# Flask Admin Filter by computed property

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I would like to filter my flask-admin results by a computed property which pulls a status from a column from MongoDB. Below is my Code which does not seem to be working. When I try this with a non-computed column it works fine. But when I try with my computed column, I can see the value is `ENABLED` but when filtering by ENABLED only I get nothing and when filtering by anything except ENABLED I get everything.

Here is the model object

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    bar = db.Column(db.String(100))

    @property
    def bar_status(self):
        status = get_status_for_bar(self.bar) # Checks mongo for record
        return status if status is not None else "Not in list"
```

View

```
# Create custom filter class
class FilterBarEnabled(BaseSQLAFilter):
    def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
        return query.filter(self.column != "ENABLED")

    def operation(self):
        return 'is Enabled'


class FooModelView(BaseModelView):
    can_view_details = True
    column_list = ('bar_status')
    page_size = 5

    column_filters = [
        FilterEnabled(column=Foo.bar_status, name='Suspicious'),
    ]
```

Comment: So you want to filter on a property you have to calculate. You realize that in order to filter, you first have to calculate the property for **all** entries in your db? It sounds like you need a [hybrid property](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/examples/sqla-hybrid_property/app.py), but I doubt you can use it in your case.

Comment: @Joost I am fine with calculating for all entries in DB before filtering... this table will not become large. Will i be able to accomplish this with hyrbrid property?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like flask admin make filter/'sort by' based on sql (it allow not to read all data from db), since computed property can't be translated into sql and you cant filter/'sort by' them